A hypothetical situation in which the State cannot prevent executing a known innocent person
I originally asked this over on Worldbuilding, was told it was a good question but not a good fit for their space, so I'll see if I get any bites here. I'll give you the TL;DR up front, and then explain why I'm asking for anyone who wants more reading material.
What legal options are generally available in U.S. death-penalty jurisdictions, to a party other than a condemned inmate or their legal counsel, to stop the inmate's execution without requiring that inmate's cooperation or consent? More specifically, is there a U.S. state in which such options are particularly limited?
That may seem like an odd question to ask, so to elaborate, this is a story idea. The setup is that a person has been convicted of murder and condemned to death, and as of the start of the narrative, the clock is winding down toward the scheduled execution date. No body was ever found, but the DA had enough other evidence (blood, weapon, etc.) to convince a jury that the victim was killed and that our protagonist killed them.
With just a few days remaining, the "victim" turns up, having faked their death and lived in another country all this time. Whatever they were running from, it wasn't our protagonist, and exactly how the protag ended up convicted of the murder is for me to invent. In any case, when this revelation becomes public, the calls to halt the execution are naturally raised in earnest.
However, the condemned person refuses to challenge their own conviction or sentence, disavowing and contesting any effort on their behalf to do so on procedural grounds. With the condemned defendant so hostile to legal action for their own benefit, no one else has standing to halt the execution and overturn the sentence, leaving the system seemingly with no other choice but to proceed with the execution for a crime that everyone now knows didn't even happen.
Why the condemned person would fight for their own death is a fair question; it's not unheard of for an admittedly guilty inmate to waive their appeals and expedite their punishment, however most condemned people, especially those with evidence of actual innocence, will naturally fight to stay alive.
Of a few plausible reasons, the one I want to play with in the story is the basic fact that the condemned person's life will have been thoroughly destroyed over the last 20 years. Divorced, destitute, shunned by society, and very likely dealing with chronic illness or disability as a direct result of their incarceration, it would not be wholly unreasonable for our would-be exoneree to try to force the State to make good on its implicit promise to end the inmate's biological life as well, both as an end to the suffering and as a middle finger to the very concept that the justice system is capable of achieving justice.

With the plot and social commentary laid out, we turn to the legal question. The conundrum presented here turns on the basic rules of "standing", that the courts do not entertain business from just anyone, a plaintiff must have cause to bring action. In this case, that person is our protagonist; in theory, nobody else, per the typical three-prong test, has that cause to stand in front of a judge and argue for overturning or even postponing the sentence, and so with the defendant uncooperative and even hostile, the Honorable Mister Google Esq. is mute on any other option for a party to bring the matter before a judge, that couldn't be challenged (including by the condemned) on grounds they lack proper standing to bring such action.
I am essentially asking, if I write the piece, whether legal bloggers will tear the premise to shreds in 5 minutes based on some day-1-of-law-school concept or procedure in US jurisprudence that I seem to be unaware of. If, in real life, the prosecutor (or some legal rando) could get an ex parte hearing with a judge on the matter, and by sundown the exoneree would be given a gentle push out the front gate in borrowed clothes, the story's not worth writing.
The idea is appealing because, on its face, there's no such procedure. The process in US law for appealing and overturning a guilty finding and/or the accompanying sentence typically functions with the willing consent of the defendant. If you take that away, then absent some fail-safe that is naturally seldom used and therefore obscure to the layman, the state would, in such a case, have little choice under its own laws but to proceed under the court order accompanying the death warrant.

There's a novel example in Texas, where the state legislature effectively postponed an execution by subpoena'ing the inmate to testify before a legislative committee, on a date later than the planned execution. https://www.nytimes.com/2024/10/17/us/texas-execution-robert-roberson.html?searchResultPosition=6

Yep, I live in Texas and am watching that legal drama play out. It almost didn't work, the appeals court overturned the judge that issued the stay which would have allowed the execution to go forward if the petitioners hadn't gotten to the TxSC first with an emergency stay request.

This is WAY longer than it needs to be. I recommend cutting at least 2/3 of the chatty dialog off to make it more concise and readable.  And per my comment on ohwilleke's answer, perhaps frame the question around the legal grounds for setting aside a conviction.

You should add a jurisdiction tag - I suspect the answer may very well be different in China to what it would be in Iran (to pick just the two most prolific executing countries).

You can refuse a Presidential Pardon; https://www.columbianprogress.com/opinion-columns/historys-lone-refusal-presidential-pardon

@MichaelHall I gave potential answerers the question being asked in the second, bolded paragraph. You don't want to read the rest, you don't have to, as I said in the first paragraph.

@TobySpeight - Edited to be more jurisdiction-specific. Part of the ideal answer would be to specify a specific State jurisdiction in which the options to overturn a death sentence without the defendant's consent are particularly limited.

The prosecution has standing to ask a court to set aside an execution, although as pending cases in the U.S. indicate, it is not clear that their request will always be honored. In a prominent case where an execution is scheduled in the U.S., the prosecutor's office asked the judge in the case to vacate the death sentence and the judge declined to do so and the body with pardon power declined to pardon or commute the sentence of the convicted defendant facing execution. SCOTUS is taking up the case.
The person with pardon power in the jurisdiction can, contrary to some case law dicta that would suggest otherwise, commute a sentence without the convicted person's consent.
The legislature can set aside a sentence without the convicted person's consent.
A court appointed guardian for the convicted person can seek to set aside a sentence despite the convicted person's stated objection to them doing so.
If the executive branch official with a power to control the people involved fails to execute someone despite a court order to do so, and the prosecution doesn't try to force it to do so, no one would have standing to force the execution to be conducted. To some extent, this is at the root of the since formalized pardon power.
Generally, no one else would have standing to be involved in whether the execution goes forward or not.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The very first paragraph is the WCS; the basic assumption is that nobody could even get a judge's official attention on the matter without the condemned person consenting to bring action. As I stated in a longer version of the question, everyone in the story besides our protag would naturally be digging deep for any excuse not to go through with the execution. A judge agreeing to block those efforts despite not just evidence but proof of actual innocence would be seen as having some ulterior motive. The enemy of the story needs to be the law itself, not any one actor within it.
